# Retrieving correct response headers (correct cookies) from a login page using fetch API?

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, http-headers, fetch-api

Not entirely sure if this is possible or not, but I'm trying to create an API for a website that does not expose a public API. To do this, I am using the fetch API to log the user in and retrieve the correct cookies in order to do other CRUD operations. What happens realistically is the user logs in, there is a 302 redirect, and that ultimately sets the right cookies for the user to use the platform.

There is various cookies being set until the session cookie is set so it's a bit confusing, but through PostMan, the redirect that it follows provides the session cookie that is needed to use the platform, but the fetch API does not follow the redirect (it does give me the redirect URl), and I'm not entirely sure how to follow through to the end.

Makes me think if I should be using a Puppeteer service to actually log the user in, then save the cookie and use that in my other services.  Might be the best bet?